# Stormcrawler not indexing content with Elasticsearch

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

When using Stormcrawler it is indexing to Elasticsearch, but not the content.

Stormcrawler is up-to-date with 'origin/master' https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler.git

Using elasticsearch-5.6.4

crawler-conf.yaml has

`indexer.url.fieldname: "url"
    indexer.text.fieldname: "content"
    indexer.canonical.name: "canonical"`

The url and title fields are indexed, but not content.

I have trying to get this working by following Julien's tutorial at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMCuWpPh-4A

Everything is working, except for the content is not being indexed into Elasticsearch. I feel like this is some small config error, but I have tried many variations with no luck. So, now I seek help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that the content is not indexed? The content field is not stored, see [ES_IndexInit.sh](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/ES_IndexInit.sh) but it should be indexed. To store it, you can modify the init script and re-run the crawl, you'd then get it back same as the other fields. To test that it is indexed, try querying on it and see how it affects the results.

Comment: Julien, you are correct. My terminology was not correct. It is indeed indexed but not stored. To store it I added "store": true.

Comment: This information is gold, it should probably be more apparent in the documentation

Comment: thanks Romain. I've added a comment on https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/blob/master/external/elasticsearch/README.md

Comment: for anyone having trouble viewing the content data, by default, _source mapping is disabled for content index, make sure to enable source by changing the flag "enabled": true to get the content data