# Stormcrawler with ES - content not stored

Tags: stormcrawler

Content / text not appearing in ES even after the indexer is configured to store content.

Stormcrawler 1.14, ES 7.0 - followed the online tutorial and the configuration change to ES_IndexInit at: [Stormcrawler not indexing content with Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47214019/stormcrawler-not-indexing-content-with-elasticsearch)

Here are the changes the content properties in ES_IndexInit.sh

```
"mappings": {
   "_source": {
    "enabled": true
    },
    "properties": {
    "content": {
       "type": "text",
       "index": "true",
       "store": true
    },
  ....
```

The crawl in local mode runs successfully and the status and metrics indices are populated with data. But the content index still remains empty:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XGET <my-es-host>:<my-es-host-port>/content/_search?pretty
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 0,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

The crawl logs do not indicate any failures and except for the missing content, the results are as specified. Looks like a configuration issue but after eliminating the usual suspects, the problem remains.

Comment: Okay - I found that I missed a step. The issue is resolved.

Comment: Can you post the missing step as answer to your own question? Might be useful for anyone else having the same problem. Thanks